# How to replace the selected value in matrix with a specific digit?

Tags: matrix, algorithm, binary

I want to replace the selected values through "RandomChoice" by 1 and all other values in matrix with 0. I want output in binary form matirx.

```
mat = Table[Subscript[m, i, j], {i, 6}, {j, 3}];
    mat // MatrixForm
    n = 18*0.5;
    k = RandomChoice[{mat[[1, 1]], mat[[1, 2]], mat[[1, 3]], mat[[2, 1]], 
       mat[[2, 2]], mat[[2, 3]], mat[[3, 1]], mat[[3, 2]], mat[[3, 3]], 
       mat[[4, 1]], mat[[4, 2]], mat[[4, 3]], mat[[5, 1]], mat[[5, 2]], 
       mat[[5, 3]], mat[[6, 1]], mat[[6, 2]], mat[[6, 3]]}, n]
```

Comment: Maybe you just need `mat = RandomInteger[1, {6, 3}]`

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your goal, you want exactly 50% 1s and the rest 0s. (By implication, either `r` or `k` is even, below.)

```
r = 6; k = 3;
RandomSample@Flatten@ConstantArray[{1, 0}, r*k/2]~Partition~k
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for making the binary matrix directly.

```
randBinary[rows_Integer, cols_Integer, ones_Integer] :=
  Module[{i, v0, v1},
    i = rows cols; 
    v0 = ConstantArray[0, i];
    v1 = List /@ RandomSample[Range[i], ones];
    Partition[ReplacePart[v0, v1 -> 1], cols]]

SeedRandom[42];
Column[{randBinary[6, 3, 9], randBinary[3, 2, 3]}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}
> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}
> ```

Note that what you asking for requires `RandomSample` not `RandomChoice`; you don't want a position to be selected more than once.